# SQL: link a column in one table to different columns in another table with joining

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called Customer, which has two columns, CustomerID and CustomerName. shown below

```
declare @customer table (CustomerID INT, CustomerName VARCHAR(10)) 
INSERT INTO @customer VALUES (1, 'Shane'), (2, 'Daniel'), (3, 'Karim'), (4, 'Eric'), (5, 'Zoe'), (6, 'Jack')
```

[image]

and another table called Age which has two columns, CustomerID and Age.

```
declare @age table (CustomerID INT, Age INT) 
INSERT INTO @Age VALUES (1, 20), (2, 19), (3, 12), (6, 30)
```

[image]

Now, I want to add an additional column called HasAge on the Customer table, if CustomerID in Customer table is also exist in Age table, then return 1 else return 0.

I have tried to use left join and CTEs to get the result. So I am wondering if there is another way to do it (without using Joins). for example. use subquery in a select statement. Actually the real case for me is more complicated. for demonstration, I use the simpler example. My goal is not to use Joins and CTEs, all done in single query or other magic functions (maybe EXISTS ?).Thanks for any help !

[image]

Comment: why do you think that using a subquery in the `select` is more "elegant"....or efficient?

Comment: The whole point of relational database design is to "relate" tables to each other using keys. JOINS are probably the most efficient solution.

Comment: @Lamak maybe I should use efficient. but for me, the real case is a lot complicated. I had to create joins and bunch of CTEs to do it. All I want is just to see if there is other way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The `left join` is concise, elegant, efficient:

```
select c.*, (case when a.customerid is null then 0 else 1 end) as has_age
from @customer c left join
     @age a
     on c.customerid = a.customerid;
```

That said, such a query is often written using `case when exists`, just in case more than one row matches:

```
select c.*
       (case when exists (select 1 from @age a where c.customerid = a.customerid)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as has_age
from @customer c;
```

That too is elegant, concise, and efficient.  If you know there is at most one row that matches, many people would prefer the `left join` version.  Personally, I'm neutral.

When I say "efficient", I mean the performance is the best that can be expected.  For real performance, you want an index on `age(customerid)`.  Both queries can make use of such an index.

Comment: Thanks a lot !  I think `case when exists` is what I am looking for !!